# database not open

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I am trying to create database using Oracle 11g R2 on windows 2008 server, when I run script to create database instance I will get the following error message

`ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open`

`grant select on  ALL_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION to public with grant option
*`

`ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open`

logged on as administrator.`

Thanks,
usermma

Answer (score 5):

Login to Oracle with root

```
su - oracle
sqlplus / as sysdba
create user username identified by password;
Exception : ORA-01109 Database not open
```

To resolve this i trie below steps and succesfully created the schema.

1. Please verify the ORA_HOMEPATH/dbs/sgadef.dbf
2. Make ensure that after shutting down the Oracle server,if you find any services running on machine by entering below command

   ```
   ps -ef | grep ora_ | grep DBName(sid)
   ```
3. Kill the processes if you find any by using kill command

   ```
   kill -9 PID
   ```
4. Please check below file exists in mentioned path; if not please create.

   ```
   ORACLE_HOMEPATH/dbs/lk<sid>
   ```
5. `start mount;` If the server is started use close immediate

   ```
   SQL> alter database close;

   Database altered.

   SQL> shutdown immediate
   ORA-01109: database not open

   Database dismounted.
   ORACLE instance shut down

   SQL> startup mount
   ORACLE instance started.

   Total System Global Area  126951228 bytes
   Fixed Size                   454460 bytes
   Variable Size             109051904 bytes
   Database Buffers           16777216 bytes
   Redo Buffers                 667648 bytes
   Database mounted.

   SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

   OPEN_MODE
   ----------
   MOUNTED

   SQL> alter database open;

   Database altered.
   ```
6. Now you can create your own schema as the database is open

   ```
   SQL> create user schemaname identified by password;

   SQL> grant resource,connect to schema name;

   grant permission succeded.
   ```

I have done above steps to create a schema when database is not open.

Answer (score 2):

Execute below Commands Sequentially....

```
> sqlplus
```

username/password = sys/*******

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount;
SQL> recover database;
SQL> alter database open;
```

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the script(s)? What does it do? Is there some reason you're not using the Database Configuration Assistant to do this? It may be simply a matter of not having the service for the instance created via `oradim.`

Comment: what do you do if there is no service for the database?