# Oracle DB service is already opened but still getting 'database not open' error in Oracle SQL Developer software

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using **Oracle DB version is 19c** and **SQL developer software version is 21**

I have tried to connect `Oracle SQL Developer` but getting below error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-01109: database not open
01109. 00000 -  "database not open"
*Cause:    A command was attempted that requires the database to be open.
*Action:   Open the database and try the command again
Vendor code 1109
```

I thought Oracle Service is down so checked it in `SQL Plus` software by following commands

```
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Fri Jan 14 2022 12:05:59 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01531: a database already open by the instance


SQL> select status from v$instance;

STATUS
------------
OPEN
```

Oracle DB service is already opened but still getting 'database not open' error in `Oracle SQL Developer software`.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we solve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with a PDB. Your root database is started but you didn't start the PDB.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  713028296 bytes
Fixed Size                  9138888 bytes
Variable Size             545259520 bytes
Database Buffers          150994944 bytes
Redo Buffers                7634944 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> conn system/pwd@pdb01
ERROR:
ORA-01109: database not open


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter pluggable database all open;

Pluggable database altered.

SQL> conn system/pwd@pdb01
Connected.
```

Comment: EdStevens Thank you so much for your great quick suggestion. It works like charm. I am facing another issue eg. when I does shutdown/restart my computer, I have to follow your suggestion and run all the commands every time. Do we have any solution so that we do not have to run all the suggested commands again and again? Can we store / set the open database state permanently Or run suggested commands at the time of start/restart computer automatically? If you have any suggestion, please share with me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If we restarts computer/server then all the opened oracle databases are closed automatically and do not open automatically after restarting computer/server. @EdStevens I am appending your suggested answer, we can call `alter pluggable database all save state;` command in oracle SQL plus after calling `alter pluggable database all open;` command. which will keep remember/open the databases state and there will no need to follow all the steps suggested by EdStevens again and again whenever system/server is restarted. Thanks a lot @EdSteven :)